# Why are there so few Covid-19 critical cases in South Korea?

Tags: statistics, epidemiology, covid-19

According to [Covid-19 statistics](https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries) there are currently 3150 people affected by Covid-19 in South Korea, while critical cases + death are 27 i.e. less the 1% of the infected. However, on Diamond Princess, where everyone is monitored being symptomatic or not (so, let's say roughly that in first approximation we can assume that this sample is unbiased), the infected are 705 with 42 critical + death cases, i.e. near 6% of the infected.

I can't believe that they are just using a sloppy test giving a lot of false positive, so, assuming also that all critical cases + death are reported: what could be a medical reason to explain this phenomenon?

https://www.worldometers.info/coronavirus/#countries

Comment: I don't know about this specific ship, but cruise ship passenger ages tend to be an inverted normal curve.  I.e. teens through 40s are very under-represented, and they are the group perhaps the least affected by the virus.

Comment: @RayButterworth Indeed, [this diagram makes that clear](https://ichef.bbci.co.uk/news/624/cpsprodpb/F197/production/_111074816_death_ratio-nc.png)